# Drush Installation

Tags: 8, drush

I have a Drupal 8 site that was installed manually.  I would like to install Drush to ease Core Updates/etc.  Is there anything that I need be concerned about doing this, since the site wasn't installed originally via Drush?

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't anything you should be concerned about :) Drush is simply an CLI tool to do some things quicker, like downloading a module.

In fact when installing with Drush you are simply automating the steps you would otherwise manually do. There are nothing that ties your Drupal installation to Drush when doing so.

Comment: This answer is accurate for Drush 8, the current stable version. Drush 9 should be installed as part of your Drupal site, as a Composer dependency (e.g. `composer require drush/drush:dev-master`)

Comment: Installing Drush locally or globally should not matter in any sense to be concerned about either way. Drush locally does not modify the code base or in any way "tie" your install to Drush. It adds it as a dependency sure.